# Grails: Get Port number in Tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat, grails

I have a Grails 2.3.6 application in which i was getting the port number using the below code:

```
System.getProperty('server.port').toInteger()
```

The above code is working fine.

Now the problem is that, am deploying the Grails app as a WAR file in Tomcat 7.

Now the above code doesn't work and am not able to get the port number.

Is there a easy way of getting the port number for Grails app instance running in Tomcat 7 server?

Comment: but why do you need it?

Comment: Grails have web services in it thats get exposed to clients. So i need the port number + server name to access the exposed interfaces in the web services methods. I already know how to get server name, all i need to know is how to get the port number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most cases you could use Grails Link Generator: http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/mapping/LinkGenerator.html

But anyway, you should understand it uses a configuration value stored in `Config.groovy`. Because Tomcat's `host:port` doesn't work when Tomcat is not facing wild web directly, usually it hidden by a frontend server, like Nginx (and I strongly recommend to do so)